# jsonRPC calling createrawtransaction in PHP

Tags: transactions, development, php

I can't get createrawtransaction to work in PHP using jsonRPC.

I found this thread https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=133769.0 from a few months ago describing the process. It won't work however, no matter how many different ways I try it...

```
$arg1 = array( array( "txid"=>$lasttx, "vout"=>$n));
$arg2 = array( $address=>$coins);


array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["txid"]=>
    string(64) "valid_tx_id_goes_here"
    ["vout"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["valid_address_goes_here"]=>
  float(0.01)
}


$this->bitcoind->createrawtransaction($arg, $arg2);
```

EDIT: All of the other commands work, like `getblock` and etc. So I'm connected to the RPC server clearly. The errors aren't helpful either -- it says unable to connect when I output the error for createrawtransaction, but all of the other commands go through the RPC fine and are able to connect. I wish I knew how to even begin debugging this.

Answer (score 2):

you should pass parameters as an array.

try like that:

```
$bitcoin->createrawtransaction(
    array(
        array(
            "txid"=>"aed23bb3ec7e93d69450d7e5ea49d52fcfbef9d380108f2be8fe14ef705fcea5",
            "vout"=>2
        ),
        array(
            "txid"=>"b28c740c66726ab2f0397be29f2d25f091b8ab353b98b9ebf9e6ccfd080cdf49",
            "vout"=>3
        ),
    ),
    array(
        "1GTDT3hYk4x4wzaa9k38pRsHy9SPJ7qPzT"=>0.006,
        "1ApD64wpNUM6GBeSmKYhsyaNwFot3FMC5y"=>0.004,
    )
);
```